# Using React props vs import , What is the best choice?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to use props in React

Let's say I have a container that use `import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl'`

And let say I have a component used in the JSX of the container.

Now, If I wanted to use **FormattedMessage** in the component also, Should I use import again in the component?
or should I send FormattedMessage as a prop to the component via the container?

Example:

```
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';

class Container {
   render() {
        return (
                <Component formattedMessage={FormattedMessage} />
        );
   }
}
```

Comment: is `formattedMessage` a react component?

Comment: Let take the two options. One is that it a React component and the other is that it just a library with functions

Comment: OK then its not a primitive like a `string`, `number` etc. i would say as a rule of thumb, if my component is depended on another __Certain__ component or library then i should import it within the same component and not let the parent take the responsibility for injecting it. Otherwise, this will make your component depended on two things now, the library __AND__ the parent

Comment: That a good thought. and what about performance? Is there any effect? The render is called few times, so I think there is... correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Your component should only render once, if you are not calling `this.setState()`

Comment: "_The render is called few times_"  - the render of what component calls few times?

Comment: Each time there is a change that need to be render... that what I mean..

Answer (score 3):

`<FormattedMessage/>` is a standalone component and passing it down to you child components in that manner completely unnecessary.

If you want to pass components from parent to child, use the special prop `children` instead.

`<Container>` render function:

```
return (<Component><FormattedMessage /></Component>)
```

`<Component>` render function:

```
return (<div>{props.children}</div>)
```

see: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Note: If you want to send the translated string into your child component as a prop, use `injectIntl` higher order component to pass the `intl` prop into your component. You can then call `intl.formatMessage({id, defaultMessage})` from within your component to translate the string you want to pass as a prop into your child component.

see: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injection-api

Comment: nice opinion, but would you care to explain why you think this opinion considered as the answer to this question? i don't think "_You should use import since FormattedMessage is a component_" qualifies as a valid explanation. With all due respect :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I think I wasn't clear enough in my question...
if you take intl.formatMessage function 
Should I send it to the child component with props? or should I import Intl again in this child component?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to not using props to transfer Components to other Components. Better import them where you need them or use Higher Order Components instead. Props are usually used to transfer data or container functions.

Comment: Can you see the comment I added in first answer?

Comment: @Ofear, Using props to transfer Components really depends on the use case of the component.